# Azure B2C extension claim error - "Request_MultipleObjectsWithSameKeyValue"

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I was trying to add extension claims to my policy and I keep getting the error "Request_MultipleObjectsWithSameKeyValue" when trying to upload my SignInSignUp policy the included the extension claim.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for my issue was found in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy). This issue I was experiencing was because I didn't include the technical profile for AAD-Common that references the default b2c-extension app registration. Once I added the technical profile in the error went a way. Here's an example of what I put in:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">{b2c-extension app registration object id}</Item>
        <Item Key="ClientId">{b2c-extension app registration client id}</Item>
    </Metadata>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I hope this helps someone since the debugging provided in B2C policy errors is not that great!

Comment: Use the [setup tool](https://aka.ms/iefsetup) to automate all dependencies.